# Medieval fantasy novel where a monster climbs out of a well

Tags: story-identification

There was a scene in a desert oasis, where the group of adventurers were sleeping. A monster of some sort crawls out of a well and starts killing. It's a medieval fantasy setting.

Comment: That's not much to go on... was it a novel or a short story? Did anything else happen other than a monster crawling out of a well?

Comment: When did you read it? What language was it in? Do you remember any names or descriptions of characters/monsters? Do you remember the cover at all? Did it seem to be aimed at any particular age group?

Comment: Looking for an answer to your question has led me to many strange and interesting places, like this website: http://hilobrow.com/adventure/ - it's a fascinating list of books, some science fiction, some fantasty, some unrelated, many I've read, many I haven't — and many I want to read now. Still looking.

Comment: Medieval fantasy, monster out of well... reminds me of Army of Darkness (the movie)

Comment: I remember such a book but not its name. I may be able to add more details though (please confirm whether this is indeed the story you are searching for). It is a 4-book series. The villain enjoys skinning his victims and uses terms from old english such as "thou". One of the adventurers fends off the monster with a magic sword that eats the lifeforce of the other adventurers. As a result, one of the adventurers has a grey strand of hair after this incident. The group has members of multiple races though I can't remember which. The title **may** contain the word "dragon".

Comment: monster coming out of a well is a recurring theme so you need a bit more information.

Answer (score 3):

"Xuthal of the Dusk"?

This was a novelette written by Robert E. Howard and originally published in the september 1933 issue of Weird Tales. It was originally called "The Slithering Shadow", here is a partial synopsis from Wikipedia

"The Slithering Shadow" is one of the original short stories starring the fictional sword and sorcery hero Conan the Cimmerian, written by American author Robert E. Howard and first published in the September 1933 issue of Weird Tales magazine. "The Slithering Shadow" is the original title, but the story is also known as "Xuthal of the Dusk" in further publications.[1] It is set in the pseudo-historical Hyborian Age and concerns Conan finding a lost city in a remote desert and encountering therein a Lovecraftian demon known as Thog."

In this, one of Howard's Conan of Cimmeria tales, Conan and his female companion are chased into the desert after barely surviving a battle, and at the brink of death they find a walled city in the desert. When they steal into the city, they find people who appear to be dead, but are actually sleeping and under the narcotic influence of the black lotus.  There is also a monster/god that the people call Thog, which I seem to remember coming out of a well, or falling into a well at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance you are thinking of *Exile's Return* by Raymond Feist? It doesn't match all that closely, but to be frank, I'm hoping that reading about it might spark a further memory about what you actually read.

Wikipedia says this about it:

> Kaspar, former Duke of Olasko, finds himself alone and without provisions on the continent of Novindus on the other side of the world after being removed from power by the Conclave of Shadows (in King of Foxes, the preceding novel). His desire for revenge must be put aside as he struggles to survive in a harsh unfamiliar land. He happens upon a farm, where his only choice is to work for food and shelter. As he is no longer under the magical influence of Leso Varen, the evil necromancer who had manipulated him while in Olasko, he begins to show compassion, and atone for his past deeds.
>
> Kaspar later joins a band of traders who have been cursed with transporting a mysterious magical suit of seemingly invulnerable animated armor, which will not allow them to leave it. Kaspar discovers the armor's origin, and is tasked with returning it across the vast ocean to the Conclave, once his enemies, now his only hope to help prevent the world's destruction.

Does that strike a bell at all?